# Deepin beeps when using two fingers on touchpad

Tags: audio, settings, deepin

Why is Deepin 20 making the same sound as it does for "volume up / volume down" action when simulating a right click by using two fingers on the touchpad (two-finger-tap)?

It started a while ago and is starting driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has something to do with the "gesture mode", you can disable it by installing `dconf-editor` and navigating to `com > deepin > dde > gesture`.

There is most probably another way to disable gestures, but the above one worked for me.